# How to add a new class to jQuery Selectbox plugin 0.3

Tags: jquery, class, plugins, drop-down-menu, addition

Hello I am developing a joomla module using jQuery Selectbox plugin 0.3 (https://github.com/riverside/select-box). jQuery Selectbox plugin converts html selectbox with `<option>` elements into `html <div> <ul> <li>` elements and thus styling them. There are predefined default options of Javascript. Everything is okay with them but I want to add an extra class option to default options. I want to add a class to `<li>` element. That should be added as an option  because I want to use it in module's default.php and make that option a dynamic php variable. That will provide to separate parent, deeper parent menu items and allow to style them differently. Thanks in advance
This is js file

```html
/*!
 * jQuery Selectbox plugin 0.3
 *
 * Copyright 2011-2015, Dimitar Ivanov (http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/)
 * Licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) license.
 * 
 * Date: Sat Nov 21 23:20:59 2015 +0300
 */
(function ($, undefined) {
    var PROP_NAME = 'selectbox',
        FALSE = false,
        TRUE = true;
    /**
     * Selectbox manager.
     * Use the singleton instance of this class, $.selectbox, to interact with the select box.
     * Settings for (groups of) select boxes are maintained in an instance object,
     * allowing multiple different settings on the same page
     */
    function Selectbox() {
        this._state = [];
        this._defaults = { // Global defaults for all the select box instances
            classHolder: "sbHolder",
            classHolderDisabled: "sbHolderDisabled",
            classSelector: "sbSelector",
            classOptions: "sbOptions",
            classGroup: "sbGroup",
            classSub: "sbSub",
            classDisabled: "sbDisabled",
            classToggleOpen: "sbToggleOpen",
            classToggle: "sbToggle",
            classFocus: "sbFocus",
            speed: 200,
            effect: "slide", // "slide" or "fade"
            onChange: null, //Define a callback function when the selectbox is changed
            onOpen: null, //Define a callback function when the selectbox is open
            onClose: null //Define a callback function when the selectbox is closed
        };
    }
    
    $.extend(Selectbox.prototype, {
        /**
         * Is the first field in a jQuery collection open as a selectbox
         * 
         * @param {Object} target
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        _isOpenSelectbox: function (target) {
            if (!target) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            var inst = this._getInst(target);
            return inst.isOpen;
        },
        /**
         * Is the first field in a jQuery collection disabled as a selectbox
         * 
         * @param {HTMLElement} target
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        _isDisabledSelectbox: function (target) {
            if (!target) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            var inst = this._getInst(target);
            return inst.isDisabled;
        },
        /**
         * Attach the select box to a jQuery selection.
         * 
         * @param {HTMLElement} target
         * @param {Object} settings
         */
        _attachSelectbox: function (target, settings) {
            if (this._getInst(target)) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            var $target = $(target),
                self = this,
                inst = self._newInst($target),
                sbHolder, sbSelector, sbToggle, sbOptions,
                s = FALSE, optGroup = $target.find("optgroup"), opts = $target.find("option"), olen = opts.length;
                
            $target.attr("sb", inst.uid);
                
            $.extend(inst.settings, self._defaults, settings);
            self._state[inst.uid] = FALSE;
            $target.hide();
            
            function closeOthers() {
                var key, sel,
                    uid = this.attr("id").split("_")[1];
                for (key in self._state) {
                    if (key !== uid) {
                        if (self._state.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            sel = $("select[sb='" + key + "']")[0];
                            if (sel) {
                                self._closeSelectbox(sel);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            sbHolder = $("<div>", {
                "id": "sbHolder_" + inst.uid,
                "class": inst.settings.classHolder,
                "tabindex": $target.attr("tabindex")
            });
            
            sbSelector = $("<a>", {
                "id": "sbSelector_" + inst.uid,
                "href": "#",
                "class": inst.settings.classSelector,
                "click": function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    closeOthers.apply($(this), []);
                    var uid = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
                    if (self._state[uid]) {
                        self._closeSelectbox(target);
                    } else {
                        self._openSelectbox(target);
                    }
                }
            });
            
            sbToggle = $("<a>", {
                "id": "sbToggle_" + inst.uid,
                "href": "#",
                "class": inst.settings.classToggle,
                "click": function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    closeOthers.apply($(this), []);
                    var uid = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
                    if (self._state[uid]) {
                        self._closeSelectbox(target);
                    } else {
                        self._openSelectbox(target);
                    }
                }
            });
            sbToggle.appendTo(sbHolder);

            sbOptions = $("<ul>", {
                "id": "sbOptions_" + inst.uid,
                "class": inst.settings.classOptions,
                "css": {
                    "display": "none"
                }
            });
            
            $target.children().each(function(i) {
                var that = $(this), li, config = {};
                if (that.is("option")) {
                    getOptions(that);
                } else if (that.is("optgroup")) {
                    li = $("<li>");
                    $("<span>", {
                        "text": that.attr("label")
                    }).addClass(inst.settings.classGroup).appendTo(li);
                    li.appendTo(sbOptions);
                    if (that.is(":disabled")) {
                        config.disabled = true;
                    }
                    config.sub = true;
                    getOptions(that.find("option"), config);
                }
            });
            
            function getOptions () {
                var sub = arguments[1] && arguments[1].sub ? true : false,
                    disabled = arguments[1] && arguments[1].disabled ? true : false;
                arguments[0].each(function (i) {
                    var that = $(this),
                        li = $("<li>"),
                        child;
                    if (that.is(":selected")) {
                        sbSelector.text(that.text());
                        s = TRUE;
                    }
                    if (i === olen - 1) {
                        li.addClass("last");
                    }
                    if (!that.is(":disabled") && !disabled) {
                        child = $("<a>", {
                            "href": "#" + that.val(),
                            "rel": that.val()
                        }).text(that.text()).bind("click.sb", function (e) {
                            if (e && e.preventDefault) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                            }
                            var t = sbToggle,
                                $this = $(this),
                                uid = t.attr("id").split("_")[1];
                            self._changeSelectbox(target, $this.attr("rel"), $this.text());
                            self._closeSelectbox(target);
                        }).bind("mouseover.sb", function () {
                            var $this = $(this);
                            $this.parent().siblings().find("a").removeClass(inst.settings.classFocus);
                            $this.addClass(inst.settings.classFocus);
                        }).bind("mouseout.sb", function () {
                            $(this).removeClass(inst.settings.classFocus);
                        });
                        if (sub) {
                            child.addClass(inst.settings.classSub);
                        }
                        if (that.is(":selected")) {
                            child.addClass(inst.settings.classFocus);
                        }
                        child.appendTo(li);
                    } else {
                        child = $("<span>", {
                            "text": that.text()
                        }).addClass(inst.settings.classDisabled);
                        if (sub) {
                            child.addClass(inst.settings.classSub);
                        }
                        child.appendTo(li);
                    }
                    li.appendTo(sbOptions);
                });
            }
            
            if (!s) {
                sbSelector.text(opts.first().text());
            }

            $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst);
            
            sbHolder.data("uid", inst.uid).bind("keydown.sb", function (e) {
                var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0,
                    $this = $(this),
                    uid = $this.data("uid"),
                    inst = $this.siblings("select[sb='"+uid+"']").data(PROP_NAME),
                    trgt = $this.siblings(["select[sb='", uid, "']"].join("")).get(0),
                    $f = $this.find("ul").find("a." + inst.settings.classFocus);
                switch (key) {
                    case 37: //Arrow Left
                    case 38: //Arrow Up
                        if ($f.length > 0) {
                            var $next;
                            $("a", $this).removeClass(inst.settings.classFocus);
                            $next = $f.parent().prevAll("li:has(a)").eq(0).find("a");
                            if ($next.length > 0) {
                                $next.addClass(inst.settings.classFocus).focus();
                                $("#sbSelector_" + uid).text($next.text());
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 39: //Arrow Right
                    case 40: //Arrow Down
                        var $next;
                        $("a", $this).removeClass(inst.settings.classFocus);
                        if ($f.length > 0) {
                            $next = $f.parent().nextAll("li:has(a)").eq(0).find("a");
                        } else {
                            $next = $this.find("ul").find("a").eq(0);
                        }
                        if ($next.length > 0) {
                            $next.addClass(inst.settings.classFocus).focus();
                            $("#sbSelector_" + uid).text($next.text());
                        }
                        break;              
                    case 13: //Enter
                        if ($f.length > 0) {
                            self._changeSelectbox(trgt, $f.attr("rel"), $f.text());
                        }
                        self._closeSelectbox(trgt);
                        break;
                    case 9: //Tab
                        if (trgt) {
                            var inst = self._getInst(trgt);
                            if (inst/* && inst.isOpen*/) {
                                if ($f.length > 0) {
                                    self._changeSelectbox(trgt, $f.attr("rel"), $f.text());
                                }
                                self._closeSelectbox(trgt);
                            }
                        }
                        var i = parseInt($this.attr("tabindex"), 10);
                        if (!e.shiftKey) {
                            i++;
                        } else {
                            i--;
                        }
                        $("*[tabindex='" + i + "']").focus();
                        break;
                    case 27: //Escape
                        self._closeSelectbox(trgt);
                        break;
                }
                e.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            }).delegate("a", "mouseover", function (e) {
                $(this).addClass(inst.settings.classFocus);
            }).delegate("a", "mouseout", function (e) {
                $(this).removeClass(inst.settings.classFocus);  
            });
            
            sbSelector.appendTo(sbHolder);
            sbOptions.appendTo(sbHolder);           
            sbHolder.insertAfter($target);
            
            $("html").on('mousedown', function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();          
                $("select").selectbox('close'); 
            });
            $([".", inst.settings.classHolder, ", .", inst.settings.classSelector].join("")).mousedown(function(e) {    
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        },
        /**
         * Remove the selectbox functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state.
         * 
         * @param {HTMLElement} target
         */
        _detachSelectbox: function (target) {
            var inst = this._getInst(target);
            if (!inst) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            $("#sbHolder_" + inst.uid).remove();
            $.data(target, PROP_NAME, null);
            $(target).show();           
        },
        /**
         * Change selected attribute of the selectbox.
         * 
         * @param {HTMLElement} target
         * @param {String} value
         * @param {String} text
         */
        _changeSelectbox: function (target, value, text) {
            var onChange,
                inst = this._getInst(target);
            if (inst) {
                onChange = this._get(inst, 'onChange');
                $("#sbSelector_" + inst.uid).text(text);
            }
            value = value.replace(/\'/g, "\\'");
            $(target).find("option[value='" + value + "']").prop("selected", TRUE);
            if (inst && onChange) {
                onChange.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null), [value, inst]);
            } else if (inst && inst.input) {
                inst.input.trigger('change');
            }
        },
        /**
         * Enable the selectbox.
         * 
         * @param {HTMLElement} target
         */
        _enableSelectbox: function (target) {
            var inst = this._getInst(target);
            if (!inst || !inst.isDisabled) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            $("#sbHolder_" + inst.uid).removeClass(inst.settings.classHolderDisabled);
            inst.isDisabled = FALSE;
            $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst);
        },
        /**
         * Disable the selectbox.
         * 
         * @param {HTMLElement} target
         */
        _disableSelectbox: function (target) {
            var inst = this._getInst(target);
            if (!inst || inst.isDisabled) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            $("#sbHolder_" + inst.uid).addClass(inst.settings.classHolderDisabled);
            inst.isDisabled = TRUE;
            $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst);
        },
        /**
         * Get or set any selectbox option. If no value is specified, will act as a getter.
         * 
         * @param {HTMLElement} target
         * @param {String} name
         * @param {Object} value
         */
        _optionSelectbox: function (target, name, value) {
            var inst = this._getInst(target);
            if (!inst) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            //TODO check name
            inst[name] = value;
            $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst);
        },
        /**
         * Call up attached selectbox
         * 
         * @param {HTMLElement} target
         */
        _openSelectbox: function (target) {
            var inst = this._getInst(target);
            //if (!inst || this._state[inst.uid] || inst.isDisabled) {
            if (!inst || inst.isOpen || inst.isDisabled) {
                return;
            }
            var el = $("#sbOptions_" + inst.uid),
                viewportHeight = parseInt($(window).height(), 10),
                offset = $("#sbHolder_" + inst.uid).offset(),
                scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
                height = el.prev().height(),
                diff = viewportHeight - (offset.top - scrollTop) - height / 2,
                onOpen = this._get(inst, 'onOpen');
            el.css({
                "top": height + "px",
                "maxHeight": (diff - height) + "px"
            });
            inst.settings.effect === "fade" ? el.fadeIn(inst.settings.speed) : el.slideDown(inst.settings.speed);
            $("#sbToggle_" + inst.uid).addClass(inst.settings.classToggleOpen);
            this._state[inst.uid] = TRUE;
            inst.isOpen = TRUE;
            if (onOpen) {
                onOpen.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null), [inst]);
            }
            $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst);
        },
        /**
         * Close opened selectbox
         * 
         * @param {HTMLElement} target
         */
        _closeSelectbox: function (target) {
            var inst = this._getInst(target);
            //if (!inst || !this._state[inst.uid]) {
            if (!inst || !inst.isOpen) {
                return;
            }
            var onClose = this._get(inst, 'onClose');
            inst.settings.effect === "fade" ? $("#sbOptions_" + inst.uid).fadeOut(inst.settings.speed) : $("#sbOptions_" + inst.uid).slideUp(inst.settings.speed);
            $("#sbToggle_" + inst.uid).removeClass(inst.settings.classToggleOpen);
            this._state[inst.uid] = FALSE;
            inst.isOpen = FALSE;
            if (onClose) {
                onClose.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null), [inst]);
            }
            $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst);
        },
        /**
         * Create a new instance object
         * 
         * @param {HTMLElement} target
         * @return {Object}
         */
        _newInst: function(target) {
            var id = target[0].id.replace(/([^A-Za-z0-9_-])/g, '\\\\$1');
            return {
                id: id, 
                input: target, 
                uid: Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999999),
                isOpen: FALSE,
                isDisabled: FALSE,
                settings: {}
            }; 
        },
        /**
         * Retrieve the instance data for the target control.
         * 
         * @param {HTMLElement} target
         * @return {Object} - the associated instance data
         * @throws error if a jQuery problem getting data
         */
        _getInst: function(target) {
            try {
                return $.data(target, PROP_NAME);
            }
            catch (err) {
                throw 'Missing instance data for this selectbox';
            }
        },
        /**
         * Get a setting value, defaulting if necessary
         * 
         * @param {Object} inst
         * @param {String} name
         * @return {Mixed}
         */
        _get: function(inst, name) {
            return inst.settings[name] !== undefined ? inst.settings[name] : this._defaults[name];
        }
    });

    /**
     * Invoke the selectbox functionality.
     * 
     * @param {Object|String} options
     * @return {Object}
     */
    $.fn.selectbox = function (options) {
        
        var otherArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        if (typeof options == 'string' && options == 'isDisabled') {
            return $.selectbox['_' + options + 'Selectbox'].apply($.selectbox, [this[0]].concat(otherArgs));
        }
        
        if (options == 'option' && arguments.length == 2 && typeof arguments[1] == 'string') {
            return $.selectbox['_' + options + 'Selectbox'].apply($.selectbox, [this[0]].concat(otherArgs));
        }
        
        return this.each(function() {
            typeof options == 'string' ?
                $.selectbox['_' + options + 'Selectbox'].apply($.selectbox, [this].concat(otherArgs)) :
                $.selectbox._attachSelectbox(this, options);
        });
    };
    
    $.selectbox = new Selectbox(); // singleton instance
    $.selectbox.version = "0.3";
})(jQuery);
```

These are default predefined options in js file

```html
function Selectbox() {
        this._state = [];
        this._defaults = { // Global defaults for all the select box instances
            classHolder: "sbHolder",
            classHolderDisabled: "sbHolderDisabled",
            classSelector: "sbSelector",
            classOptions: "sbOptions",
            classGroup: "sbGroup",
            classSub: "sbSub",
            classDisabled: "sbDisabled",
            classToggleOpen: "sbToggleOpen",
            classToggle: "sbToggle",
            classFocus: "sbFocus",
            speed: 200,
            effect: "slide", // "slide" or "fade"
            onChange: null, //Define a callback function when the selectbox is changed
            onOpen: null, //Define a callback function when the selectbox is open
            onClose: null //Define a callback function when the selectbox is closed
        };
    }
```

I have these options in my default.php of module as php variables like this. that is okay

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict(); 

        jQuery(function () {

            jQuery("#jqjumpmenu_id").selectbox({
            classHolder: '<?php echo $params->get( 'classHolder');?>',
            classSelector:'<?php echo $params->get( 'classSelector');?>',
            classOptions: '<?php echo $params->get( 'classOptions');?>',
            classGroup: '<?php echo $params->get( 'classGroup');?>'

        });
});
        </script>
```

I want to have an extra option for `<li>` element like LinkClass. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see way too many trailing commas in that last snippet.  ...not to mention that you are manually crafting a js object which is classically unstable and never advisable.  You should be letting php's `json_encode()` do all of the work of forming a json string, then just pass it to the js scripting.  This way your data structure will never be to blame when your application runs afoul.  See this demo: https://3v4l.org/rJoH5  Please always post your Joomla development questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks mickmackusa I will follow your advises. I just wanted to show what am I trying to do in my default.php and forgot about commas while writing here. I have corrected them and still need help on js file to add a class. Thanks again.

Comment: In your edited snippet, I still see an erroneous trailing comma in your js object.  Again, you must do this work in php as demo'ed.

Comment: I have just corrected :) thanks